# How to find the correct path for a link in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, path

I got a problem with a link I've tried to make. I want to have a page with an article, and a link to the author page of it. Iv's try 100 differents version but i don't know how to do... 
Here is my code :

```
<a <% link_to " Par : #{@article.author.pseudo}", user_path(User.where(user_id: @author_id) %></a>
```

or with this path : `user_path(Article.find(params[:id]).author_id)`

If you know how I can resolve that... Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap link_to helper into `<a>`tag, it is already generated by the helper. `where` returns the collection, not the instance - that's why your code does not work. You already have needed user instance in `@article.author`, just use it

```
<%= link_to "Par : #{@article.author.pseudo}", user_path(@article.author) %>
```

Comment: Happy to help! Please, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helped

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to link directly to the author:

```
<%= link_to "Par : #{@article.author.pseudo}", @article.author %>
```

Comment: With that code, there are not error message but when I clicked on the button nothing happend..

Comment: Nothing at all? Please post the code that is around the above link. Note that you don't need `<a>` as `link_to` will generate that for you.

Comment: Exact, that was the problem, the <a>. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```rb
<%= link_to("Par : #{@article.author.pseudo}", @article.author) %>
```

Comment: I got an syntax error message : syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'
...er.where(user_id: @author_id) ;@output_buffer.safe_append='<...